# What is considered the best practise for naming action types in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need to load posts for the page so I call this action creator:

```
export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/posts');
    const posts = response.json();
    dispatch({
      type: SET_POSTS,
      posts: response.posts
    });
  } catch(err) {}
};
```

Should I call the action type `SET_POSTS`? Should it be called `GET_POSTS` instead?

I went with `SET_POSTS` because technically the post has already been fetched at that point and all thats left to do is to set the posts in state.

What is the best practise regarding naming action types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now recommend writing action types as [`"domain/eventName"`](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#write-action-types-as-domaineventname), rather than `"SOME_THING"`.  We also recommend [modeling actions as "events", not "setters"](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters) conceptually.

In this case, I'd suggest something like `{type: "posts/postsReceived"}`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is totally fine to name it as `SET_POSTS` as long your team is in the same page with the naming convention. Also try to be consistent in providing similar naming convention to your other reducers as well. Eg: `SET_COMMENTS`.

as you are using thunk, you can also consider to use something like

```js
GET_POSTS // make api call.
GET_POSTS_SUCCESS // set the state after successful retrieval of posts
GET_POSTS_ERROR // set the error state
```